Webapi latency in production
Our webapi deployed as an Azure webapp is slow or experiencing performance issues in production. The same code runs faster on dev and staging slots. I understand that there may be places in the api where code can be fine-tuned but we are pretty sure, there is some sort of network latency happening. What metrics should I check?
It has only one instance and is on a (P2v3: 1). I have asked them to scale out but what are the metrics I should be looking for to actually find the reason.
I don't want to assume that scaling out is the solution.
I gathered some screenshots, but nothing really stands out.

Database is a sql server managed instance

Memory Percentage

CPU percentage

Http queue length

API general settings



why vote down? Interesting :)

Please [edit] to also provide details of your deployment environment, such as which platform/service are you using. Please also tag it with the more relevant technologies, ex. [tag:azure]? That would narrow down your question, because currently it is quite vague.

If you did not already try and setup application insights. With a .NET stack you could get quite a few informations. At the very least the timings of the requests as seen by the application and even the time spent calling dependencies (services, like your DB).

@Irwene: Thank you for looking at this question . Our webapi talks to another 3rd party api. We think the connection or network to this 3rd party Api is slow. Can app insights show us such visibility?

Properly implemented, it should
